# How to set the text Padding to a google slide shape via Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, shapes, text-formatting, google-slides

How to set the text Padding to a google slide shape via Google Script?

In my google script I just append a slide, and applied an Style.
But I cannot change top padding to my textbox shapes.

The code runs just fine but I need to set Padding to zero.
How can I do that?
Any help? Please.... thanks

```
var shapeCat = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 370, 50, 349, 20);   
var textRange = shapeCat.getText();
var insertedText = textRange.appendText("kITTY tEXT");
insertedText.getTextStyle()
    .setBold(true)
    .setFontSize(14)
    .setForegroundColor('#2D2D2D');
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the sample result you want?

Comment: I need to create a textBox with no spaces between the text and its borders borders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide a sample Document for replicating the issue of your script? By this, I would like to think of your solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for answer to this as well. Neither the [Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) class nor the [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style) class provide any methods for manipulating the padding that offsets text inside a shape. It appears Google did not deem anyone would want to do this programmatically :(

Note: it can be set manually when a shape is selected under `Format options > Text fitting`

This is the padding being referred to:

[image: padding screenshot]

Comment: The only way is create a slide manually, copy it and use as template, then change the text, if possible.
Do it manual is not a solution. :(